# How put "DISTINCT" key word in cakephp query?

Tags: cakephp

I have code like this

```
$this->Customer->setSource('customer');
        $this->Customer->find('first',array('fields'=>" IF(assigned_id.assigned_id is NULL, 
                                             CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`team_members`.`user_id`)),'=>TEAM')"));
```

my required output is this

```
SELECT  IF(assigned_id.assigned_id is NULL, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`team_members`.`user_id`)),'=>TEAM') FROM `ctk_customer` AS `Customer` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 1
```

But i get this output

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(assigned_id.assigned_id is NULL, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`team_members`.`user_id`)),'=>TEAM') FROM `ctk_customer` AS `Customer` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you can try with `find('all')`

Comment: i tried  find('all'), find('count'). but get wrong result

Comment: `IF(assigned_id.assigned_id` Did you mean only one assigned_id there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->Customer->setSource('customer');
        $this->Customer->find('first',array('fields'=>" IF(assigned_id.assigned_id is NULL, 
                                             CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(`team_members`.`user_id`)),'=>TEAM')"));
```

Answer (score 0):

[it looks like](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) you can just do it like this :

```
array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'), //array of field names
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'), //string or array defining order
    'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset'=>n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
)
```